# Excel VBA - check if active worksheet is first worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check if the active worksheet is the first worksheet in the workbook. This code isn't working at all, but I'm hoping I was on the right track.

```
Sub CheckFirstSheet()
If Sheets(1) = ActiveSheet Then MsgBox "This is the first worksheet."
If Sheets(1) <> ActiveSheet Then MsgBox "This is not the first worksheet."
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveSheet.Index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple

```
Sub test()
If ActiveSheet.Index = 1 Then MsgBox "This is the first worksheet."
If ActiveSheet.Index <> 1 Then MsgBox "This is not the first worksheet."
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work if more than one workbook is open.

Comment: The same is valid for the example you provided (just tested). It seems that both codes act on the active workbook.

Comment: That's because `Sheets` (unqualified) is a global.  This will be inconclusive for any `Worksheet` reference that is qualified (or if it's used from the `ThisWorkbook` module).

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare reference types with `=` and `<>` - you have to use `Is`:

```
Sub CheckFirstSheet()
    If Sheets(1) Is ActiveSheet Then
        MsgBox "This is the first worksheet."
    Else
        MsgBox "This is not the first worksheet."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Sub CheckFirstSheet()

If ActiveSheet.Index = 1 Then
    MsgBox "This is the first worksheet."
Else
    MsgBox "This is not the first worksheet."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not a fully qualified argument, but it does work if multiple workbooks are open

Comment: Right, that's the point though - it *only* works if the arguments aren't fully qualified.  `ActiveSheet` is a global, but any fully qualified sheet reference has to belong to a specific workbook.